# Spy on mock service worker (msw)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm starting to use the [msw (mock service worker)](https://mswjs.io/) after watching [this example](https://github.com/leighhalliday/msw-example) of how to use it for testing API calls in React applications.

Is there any way that we can spy on the mock service worker?

For example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, act, await } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { rest } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'

import SearchBox from '.'

const fakeServer = setupServer(
  rest.get(
    'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search',
    (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ data: { photos: { photo: [] },},}))
  )
)

beforeAll(() => {fakeServer.listen()})
afterEach(() => {fakeServer.resetHandlers()})
afterAll(() => fakeServer.close())

test('it calls Flickr REST request when submitting search term', async () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<SearchBox />)
  const input = getByLabelText('Search Flickr')
  const submitButton = getByLabelText('Submit search')

  await act(async () => {
    await userEvent.type(input,'Finding Wally')
    await userEvent.click(submitButton)
  })

  await wait()

  // TODO: assert that the fakeServer was called once and with the correct URL
})
```

The component to test looks like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import './index.css'

function SearchBox({ setPhotos }) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  const handleTyping = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSearchTerm(event.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      const restURL = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
      }&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1'&text=${encodeURIComponent(
        searchTerm
      )}`
      const { data } = await axios.get(restURL)
      const fetchedPhotos = data.photos.photo
      setPhotos(fetchedPhotos)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <section style={styles.container}>
      <form action="" method="" style={styles.form}>
        <input
          aria-label="Search Flickr"
          style={styles.input}
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleTyping}
        />
        <button
          aria-label="Submit search"
          style={styles.button}
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          SEARCH
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}
```

I have got a working test, but I feel it leans towards an implementation test since it uses a spy on the `setPhotos`

```js
test('it calls Flickr REST request when submitting search term', async () => {
  const fakeSetPhotos = jest.fn(() => {})
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<SearchBox setPhotos={fakeSetPhotos} />)
  const input = getByLabelText('Search Flickr')
  const submitButton = getByLabelText('Submit search')

  await act(async () => {
    await userEvent.type(input, 'Finding Walley')
    await userEvent.click(submitButton)
  })

  await wait()

  expect(fakeSetPhotos).toHaveBeenCalledWith([1, 2, 3])
})
```

Comment: Why do you consider setPhotos being a test double indicative of an implementation test? Calling back the prop is part of the *behaviour* expected of the component.

Comment: I'm passing down a function `setPhotos` to update the parent state, but it could be that I was using react context instead then it would not come as a prop.

Comment: But that would be a change in behaviour, at the level of this component. If you wanted to be able to change how the parent and child communicate without changing the test, you shouldn't be testing at the interface between them. And please don't put tags in titles, that's what tags are for.

Comment: But anyway none of that is directly relevant to what you actually are asking, because the issue is really nothing to do with the `setPhotos` behaviour and more about the *other* part of the component's behaviour, wanting to know that it makes the request it's supposed to. Part of the problem is separation of concerns - if you extracted the actual request-making to a collaborator, then it could be replaced with a simple test double and the component just needs to give it the search term (`expect(service.getPhotos).toHaveBeenCalledWith(searchInput)`).

Comment: That is a good point that an interface test between parent and child is valuable. I would also like to test that it calls the right REST URL.

Comment: breaking it out to a separate service as a custom hook makes good sense . I just still needs to spy on the fake server

Answer (score 10):

The devs at [mswjs](https://github.com/mswjs) are really nice and helpful. They took their time [to advice](https://github.com/mswjs/examples/issues/30#issuecomment-673986172) me on how to approach it.

## TLDR;

The current working test I got is fine - just suggested an alternative to `jest.fn()` - I do like the readability of the their suggestion:

```js
test('...', async () => {
  let photos

  // Create an actual callback function
  function setPhotos(data) {
    // which does an action of propagating given data
    // to the `photos` variable.
    photos = data
  }

  // Pass that callback function as a value to the `setPhotos` prop
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<SearchBox setPhotos={setPhotos} />)

  // Perform actions:
  // click buttons, submit forms

  // Assert result
  expect(photos).toEqual([1, 2, 3])
})
```

Another thing I wanted to test was that it actually calls a valid REST URL.

> You can reflect an invalid query parameter in the response resolver.
> If the query parameter is missing/invalid your real server would not
> produce the expected data, right? So with MSW your "real server" is
> your response resolver. Check the presence or value of that query
> parameter and raise an error in case that parameter is invalid.
>
> ```
> rest.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search', 
>      (req, res, ctx) => {   const method = req.url.searchParams.get('method')
>
>   if (!method) {
>     // Consider a missing `method` query parameter as a bad request.
>     return res(ctx.status(400))   }
>
>   // Depending on your logic, you can also check if the value of the `method`   // parameter equals to "flickr.photos.search".
>
>   return res(ctx.json({ successful: 'response' })) })
> ```
>
> Now, if your app misses the method query parameter in the request URL, it would get a 400 response, and shouldn't call the setPhotos callback in case of such unsuccessful response.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid mocking you could spy on `axios.get` and assert that it was called correctly.

```
test('it calls Flickr REST request when submitting search term', async () => {
  const getSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<SearchBox />)
  const input = getByLabelText('Search Flickr')
  const submitButton = getByLabelText('Submit search')

  await act(async () => {
    await userEvent.type(input,'Finding Wally')
    await userEvent.click(submitButton)
  })

  await wait()

  expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Comment: It's a fine suggestion (and I upvoted it) - the only beef I have with it is that it's an implementation test and not BDD test

Answer (score 1):

You could create a jest.fn() mock and use msw to listen to the request.

```js
const getRequestSpy = () => {
  const requestSpy = jest.fn();
  server.events.on('request:start', async (request) => {
    if (
      request.method === 'GET' &&
      matchRequestUrl(new URL(request.url), 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search')
    ) {
      requestSpy();
    }
  });
  return requestSpy;
};
```

Then in the test:

```js
describe('TestSuite', () => {
  let requestSpy: jest.Mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    requestSpy = getRequestSpy();
    server.use(
      rest.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search', (_, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(200));
      })
    );
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    server.events.removeAllListeners();
  })

  test('it calls Flickr REST request when submitting search term', async () => {
    const { getByLabelText } = render(<SearchBox />);
    const input = getByLabelText('Search Flickr');
    const submitButton = getByLabelText('Submit search');

    await act(async () => {
      await userEvent.type(input, 'Finding Wally');
      await userEvent.click(submitButton);
    });

    await wait();

    expect(requestSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });
});
```

They do however mention in their [docs](https://mswjs.io/docs/best-practices/avoid-request-assertions/) that you should avoid request assertions. But sometimes, there is no other way around it.